# Is it possible to use nhibernate.search and nhibernate 3.0

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate.search

Guys,
I haven't found any nhibernate.search assemblies compatible with nh3. Looks like it haven't completed yet. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Open it in visual studio, change the reference and press ctrl+shift+b?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that's true. For my needs, I temporary use this brunch https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/branches/NHibernate.Search-with-NH-3.0

Answer (score 2):

This was posted on the S#arp Architechture mailing list today by Seif Attar

---

I have just built and uploaded this to contrib develop branch, you can download from

https://github.com/seif/Sharp-Architecture-Contrib/tree/develop/ReferencedAssemblies

NHibernate.Search is in Nhibernate folder, and Lucene.Net 2.9.2 is in the lucene folder.